# How to get onBackPressed event in a service?

Tags: android, android-service, android-windowmanager

Trying to make something similar to facebook chat head. When we click on the chat head it opens up the chat. Now when we press back button it closes the popup of chat. How to capture onBackPressed event in a service?

Comment: service not made for get backpress. you cant get any event on backpress

Comment: dear, service is faceless activity, how can you detect onBackPressed();

Comment: Yes, I get that. But how facebook messenger gets backbutton click event.

Comment: @Mohit how to receive broadcast for back pressed event?

Comment: you have to create custom for that

Comment: @Mohit can u please provide some sample receiver for bacpressed event. Unable to find one!

Comment: check my [this sample app](https://github.com/mohit008/Android-BroadCast-Tutorial)

Comment: You can't get backpressed event in a service because it's running on the background

Comment: @Mohit service is not attached to an activity how it will send a broadcast for back press event!

Comment: you dont have to send event , just broadcast an intent (with string) to your service

Comment: @Mohit From where will i send the broadcast?

Answer (score 1):

This might work :

make the window or view you show via service as focusable, 
add a onKeylistener(for e.g. on rootview or other) and listen for KEYCODE_BACK.

Comment: made sure your view is focusable? only focusable views can recieve key events via keylistener.

Comment: Activity.java in framework also does something similar, search for backpress, http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/Activity.java,

You must get key events on focused view to track Back.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library [here](https://github.com/ericbhatti/floaties) to make floating windows like facebook chat heads. This library's floating windows closes on back button press.